# Do you need all the complication images for a watchOS extension?

Tags: apple-watch

I'm making a watch extension for my app. On the Watch Extension folder, there is an Assets.xcassets folder with a complications subfolder with a bunch of complications, each one with multiple spots for images.

[image]

My extension is very simple. I just want the logo to show for all complications. Should I just delete it? Leave it empty? Or do you I actually have to make all those images?

On the Watch folder, there is another asset folder with the AppIcon. I added all the sizes for the icon there.